# How to conditionally add / update dates on row update in Excel using Visual Basic

Tags: excel, vba

My data is in an Excel table where the users are able to manipulate the data in rows A through S.

I am trying to figure out a way to accomplish the following tasks:

- Populate the cell in Column P with today’s date when a new row is created
- Populate the cell in Column U with the date that the last update was made to any cell between columns A through S in the row

When data in column D is updated, I need other columns to populate a date depending on the value in column D:

- If D is updated to “Approved”, then today’s date should be populated in Column R
- If D is updated to “Funded”, then today’s date should be populated in Column S
- Etc

I have been looking up examples of code, but being new to Visual Basic I am having a hard time finding examples of each of these, especially the “created” and “status update” one, and im having a tough time adapting what I do find to my scenario.

Any help would be appreciated!

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim WorkRng As Range, roww As Long
    Dim rng As Range
    Set WorkRng = Intersect(Range("A:S"), Target)
    If Not WorkRng Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
            For Each rng In WorkRng
                roww = rng.Row
                If Not rng.Value = "" Then
                    Cells(roww, "U").Value = Now
                    Cells(roww, "U").NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
                End If
                If ActiveCell.Column = "D" And rng.Value = "Approved" Then
                    Cells(roww, "R").Value = Now
                    Cells(roww, "R").NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
                End If
            Next
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Your best bet for getting help here is *post the code you tried* and explain what it's doing/not doing which is different from what you want.

Comment: I am working in the Worksheet change event, I’m just getting lost on what the code should be. I’ll try to post the code, it’s just on my work computer and I’m logged into here on my tablet :)

Comment: Edited and added the current code I have so far.  The part about updating the date in column U when any information in the row is updated is working.  Nothing else is

Comment: Should ActiveCell.Column be rng.Column?

Comment: Haha - I have no idea Raymond. I'm trying to piece together a few code snippets I've found and trying to make it work!  I did finally cobble something together, though, which seems to be working.  I'm open to feedback on how to improve it!

Comment: @Alan well its weird that you reference `ActiveCell` in the loop when everything else in it refers to `rng`. From your description it sounds like it should be `rng.Column`

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea if this is the best way to do it, but as far as I can tell this is working to accomplish what I was trying to do.  I'm open to suggestions on how to improve it!!

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim WorkRng As Range, StatusRng As Range, roww As Long, Srow As Long
    Dim rng As Range, Srng As Range
    Set WorkRng = Intersect(Range("A:S"), Target)
    If Not WorkRng Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
            For Each rng In WorkRng
                roww = rng.Row
                If Not rng.Value = "" Then
                    Cells(roww, "U").Value = Now
                    Cells(roww, "U").NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
                End If
                If rng.Column = Range("D:D").Column And rng.Value = "Approved" Then
                    Cells(roww, "R").Value = Now
                    Cells(roww, "R").NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
                End If
                If rng.Column = Range("D:D").Column And rng.Value = "Approved w/ Conditions" Then
                    Cells(roww, "Q").Value = Now
                    Cells(roww, "Q").NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
                End If
                If rng.Column = Range("D:D").Column And rng.Value = "Funded" Then
                    Cells(roww, "S").Value = Now
                    Cells(roww, "S").NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
                End If
                If Not rng.Value = "" And Cells(roww, "P").Value = "" Then
                    Cells(roww, "P").Value = Now
                    Cells(roww, "P").NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
                End If
            Next
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: `rng.Column = Range("D:D").Colum` could be simplified to `rng.Column = 4`. Definitely upvoted for you figuring out a solution to your question!

Comment: Nice to know that would work as well - thanks BigBen!